# egrep in python

Tags: grep

so thanks to this forum, I currently have this code, which takes an output from a programme I have and saves it in a file:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import os

os.chdir('./P574/J0998-1034')
os.system('vap -c freq *.SFTC > 1400list.txt')
```

I wanted to add a filter (so take only lines that contained "1369.000", so I amended the last line to:

```
os.system('vap -c freq *.SFTC | egrep 1369.000 > 1400listfilt.txt')
```

But I really want it to take lines that contain EITHER "1369.000" OR "1433.000". I tried:

```
os.system('vap -c freq *.SFTC | egrep 1369.000|1433.000 > 1400listfilt.txt' )
```

But I got the error message: "sh: 1433.000: command not found
egrep: write error: Broken pipe"

How can I make it check for two values? Also.. is this the best way to do what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would surround the arguments in single quotes as such:

```
egrep '(1369.000|1433.000)'
```

The shell is telling you that it could not redirect the output of `egrep` to the program `1433.000` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It didn't seem to like that though. I got the following error message: os.system('vap -c freq *.SFTC | egrep ('1369.000|1433.000') > 1400listfilt.txt' )
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try putting the single quotes around the parentheses.

Comment: oh sorry! It still didn't work, but when I used " instead of ' it worked. Thank you!

Comment: That's because you used single quotes for the entire string, but at least it works now.  Glad to help.